# Event Listener for button not working- vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I am following [this](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_self) W3c tutorial on this slideshow feature that contains 'OnClick' events within the HTML. However, I am trying to reproduce the same using JavaScript in a separate file (which is properly connected) and use the 'click' event listener instead to perform the same task which is going right and left within the slideshow. However, it does not seem to be working- there are no JS console errors and the syntax is fine. I have put the JS code into an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<h2 class="w3-center">Manual Slideshow</h2>

<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.pexels.com/photo/scenic-view-of-the-mountain-734659/" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://www.pexels.com/photo/scenic-view-of-the-mountain-734659/" style="width:100%">

  <button id="left" class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" >&#10094;</button>
  <button id="right" class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" >&#10095;</button>
</div>

<script src="scripts.js" ></script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
(function(){
let left = document.getElementById("left");
let right = document.getElementById("right");
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
};

left.addEventListener("click", plusDivs(-1));
right.addEventListener("click", plusDivs(1));
})();
```

JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/pf0t32h6/

Comment: On a side note. In JsFiddle you don't need to reference the script. <script src="scripts.js" ></script>. For me that was springing an error.

Comment: @JasonAllshorn Will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are calling the function (`plusDivs`) immediatly instead of passing a reference to it, causing the return value of `plusDivs()` (which happens to be just undefined) will be passed to the `addEventListener` of both of your buttons. You could either use `bind()`, or put the function call in a function.

Either `bind`

```
left.addEventListener("click", plusDivs.bind(null, -1));
```

or use another function

```
left.addEventListener("click", function() { plusDivs(-1); });
```

Answer (score 1):

You invoking `plusDivs` when the script run so it returns `undefined`.

```
left.addEventListener("click", function(){
    plusDivs(-1)
});
right.addEventListener("click", function(){
    plusDivs(1)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.